# Calibrating the probabilities of Ridge Classifier on imbalanced dataset

Tags: probability, distributions, probability-inequalities

I have a classification project on an imbalanced dataset (HomeCredit Kaggle dataset) and I have chosen Ridge Classifier (sklearn's implementation) as the most efficient both in terms of time and in terms of my performance indicator (ROC AUC score).

The initial dataset is widely imbalanced (0.92 TARGET = 0, 0.08 TARGET = 1) so I had to perform SMOTE oversampling to the train dataset to bring back the ratio to 50/50. There are about 450 features with 300k samples.

On a previous posts, commenters seemed dubious on the merits of oversampling. I have tried different ratios (from the intial ratio to 1 or 50/50) and there has been a linear improvement of ROC AUC when increasing the ratio and bringing it up to 1. So I think this is necessary in this case, possibly because of the high number of features.

Since I am requested to provide probabilities for my predictions, I have extended the RidgeClassifier class with softmax as such (from research on another post) :

```
class RidgeClassifierWithProba(RidgeClassifier):
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        d = self.decision_function(X)
        d_2d = np.c_[-d, d]
        return softmax(d_2d)
```

The final scores I get from my model are relatively good with a final ROC AUC score of 0.76 when taking into account those probabilities (0.70 with just the predictions). Top Kagglers have only been able to reach 0.805 during the competition so I think it is close enough.

The problem is that the histogram of probabilities show that there is no separation between the 2 classes, with an almost normally distributed density :

[image]

I tried to implement the following CalibratedClassifierCV functions to improve this distribution :

```
pipe_iso = CalibratedClassifierCV(final_pipe, cv=2, method="isotonic")
pipe_sig = CalibratedClassifierCV(final_pipe, cv=2, method="sigmoid")
```

But it make the probability distribution even worse, with all of them skewed towards the majority class :

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? Is my model not good enough to have a separated probabilities histogram? What else can I do to calibrate my probabilities?

**Edit :** As requested by @Ben Reiniger, I uploaded my work on Kaggle :
[Link to Kagggle](https://www.kaggle.com/octaveati/home-credit-scoring) and am posting more code below. This is my final pipeline :

```
#Defining our final pipeline
final_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('cat_encode', cat_encode),
    ('imputation', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('var', boruta),
    ('os', ADASYN()),
    ('ridge',RidgeClassifierWithProba(alpha=6.967)),
    ], memory="./Cache/")
```

If it makes any difference, this is an Imbalearn pipeline and not a Sklearn pipeline since it implements oversampling.

Cat encoder is a Column Transformer that imputes categorical fields based on the number of unique categories (One Hot when nunique <= 5 and WOE when nunique >5). Boruta is a FunctionTransformer built from a Boruta Selector.

Here are my results on the test set (results on the train set are similar) :

[image]

To clarify my statement about the ROC AUC Score, when I feed only the predicted results from the base Ridge Classifier into the roc_auc_score function it returns 0.7 while when I feed it the probabilities it returns 0.76 (because it smoothes the curve).

```
final_pipe.fit(X_train_reduced, y_train)
train_predictions = final_pipe.predict(X_train_reduced)
proba_train = final_pipe.predict_proba(X_train_reduced)[:, 1]
test_predictions = final_pipe.predict(X_test)
proba_test = final_pipe.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

roc_auc_score(y_test, test_predictions) #Returns 0.7
roc_auc_score(y_test, proba_test) #Returns 0.76
```

When calibrating the probablities with my isotonic calibrater, I get the following "stacked" bar chart, which **looks good** but actually the colors are the probabilities for each class. So unless I'm misunderstanding something it means that with a probability threshold of 0.5 this would predict that **all test results are in the Majority (blue) class**.

```
test_prob = pipe_iso.predict_proba(X_test)

plt.hist(test_prob, stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For comparison this is the same chart with my uncalibrated pipeline :

[image]

Comment: just use a logistic regression instead of piling on one hack on top of another (as I assume previous posts have suggested). and see https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/prediction-bias

Comment: Logistic Regression returns a similar probability distribution, along with a less performant ROC and a fifty-fold increase in calculation time. What are the hacks you mention? The only thing I would qualify as a hack here is extending the Ridge Classifier with probabilities but it’s in line with what Logistic Regression returns.

Comment: using ridge classifier instead of a model that will output a probability
using smote
adding a softmax 
trying to add another calibration layer on top of softmax

[ you can probably adjust the computation time of the logistic regression]

Comment: Can you share some of your work (kaggle notebook?)?  Does "(0.70 with just the predictions)" mean the hard class predictions?  (You could use `decision_function` rather than softmax'ing, for the purposes of ROC.)  Perhaps the histogram of scores would be more informative if you used stacked bars for the two classes.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks for your answer! I have clarified my statement in the main post, and also posted some code as well as a Kaggle link :)

Comment: @seanv507 I mean regardless of the Linear model chosen you would have needed oversampling (adasyn not smote). If you just feed the cleaned data into Logistic Regression you get a ROC AUC Score train of 0.95 and 0.51 on the test set. (or rather validation since I did not try it out on the test set)

Comment: That the original data gives you such high training AUC but the oversampled does not seems strange to me.  // Your first new histogram isn't very interesting; the orange and blue are just mirror images (probabilities of 0 and 1).  I'm not sure what the second one is representing; it can't be the two classes, because there would be far less of one color.

Comment: The first histogram is returned by plotting histplot stacked on the predict_proba of my calibrated pipeline while the second one is the predict_proba of my classifier without calibration. 
I also have a hard time understanding what they represent…

Comment: I was thinking of something like this for the histogram: `neg_probs = test_prob[y_test == 0, 1]; pos_probs = test_prob[y_test == 1, 1]; plt.hist([neg_probs, pos_probs], stacked=true)`.  (I haven't tested this code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the histogram of probabilities show that there is no separation between the 2 classes, with an almost normally distributed density

With an AUROC of 0.76, I think this is expected.  If the distribution density was bimodal (and performance not trash, so that most of the data with values in the two peaks are correctly sorted), you'd get a large number of pairs put in the correct order (AUROC having one interpretation as "ratio of positive-negative pairs that appear in the correct order by score).  And just because the scores are unimodel doesn't mean that the classes aren't *somewhat* well separated, hence my suggestion in a comment to split the bars by class.

> But it make the probability distribution even worse, with all of them skewed towards the majority class

That's not worse!  The majority class does dominate, and so the probabilities *should* be skewed towards it.

Note that the last bin in the sigmoid plot has very little data in it, so take the very low positive rate with a grain of salt.  (You could also use `strategy='quantile'` instead of the default `'uniform'` to make the bins in the plot equal-volume rather than equal-width.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughtful answrer. I have made significant edits in my main post and added a Kaggle link as requested. What I meant with the calibrated probabilities histogram is that there is no sample with a probability of belonging to the minority class > 0.5. So unless I'm completely misunderstanding what it represents I think it would mean that the calibrated model predicts that all samples belong to the minory class. I have provided the probability histograms as an edit also. It's not impossible that I'm completely misrepresenting the histograms though, I'm still learning!

Comment: The point is that calibration is giving you better probability estimates, and that those are naturally skewed low. You shouldn't pay much attention to any results relying on a 50% cutoff; your lender probably won't want to lend money to someone with a 49% probability of default!

Comment: I understand but then I have a hard time figuring out how the pipeline actually predicts the minority class when all samples have a > 50% probability of belonging to the majority class.

Comment: @Octave You need to decide how to consume the predicted probabilities.  For example, you might compute the expected profit of the loan and approve positive-expected-value (or maybe some minimum positive threshold profitability) applications, which may translate to a probability threshold of say 5%.

Comment: In that case, the Ridge Classifying algorithm automatically determines the threshold? Is it possible to know what threshold it selects?

Comment: @Octave Ridge sets a threshold at zero (the regression being fitted with targets $\pm1$); threshold analysis is generally left up to you in sklearn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very insightful answers and I apoligize for being dense but here is what I don’t understand : Ridge Regression takes 0-1 as an input, converts them in -1/1, applies regression and predicts classes based on the sign of the results. Now when I apply the soft max to the decision function it returns “logical” probabilities, IE when the probability is > 0.5 it predicts the class.

Comment: Now when I calibrate the probabilities all of them are above 0.5 for the majority class and below 0.5 for the minority class. How am I supposed to consume this distribution? It just seems illogical to me and I feel like these probabilities are worthless because I wouldn’t be able to predict the class based on them.

Comment: @Octave I feel like you're focusing on the two probabilities too much.  Ignore the probability of non-default, it's just the complement to the probability of default.  And maybe think less about the classification meaning "this person will (likely) default" and more about "I shouldn't lend to this person, I will (on average) lose money".  The latter requires a bit more analysis (what's expected loss/profit if they default/not?), but after that the threshold you choose may be quite small.  (Real business is more nuanced, but this is a good start to understanding the imbalance in decisioning.)

Comment: I guess there is more to say about just the probabilities though.  It's probably _correct_ to say that no individual has a 50% chance of defaulting.  That would require a _really strong_ indicator of bad credit (or fraud).  The main reason of defaults (in prime customers) are random external costs that would be very hard to predict at time of application.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @BenReiniger this makes a lot more sense now!